# Make automatic multiplication in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

Hi guys i'm try learning VBA Excel , but i have some problem in my project

Here my code

```
For p = 10 To 36
    If IsNumeric(Range("E" & p).Value) Then
        E = Range("E" & p).Value
        result2(p) = E * 1000
        Range("E" & p).Value = result2(p)
    End If
Next p
```

i'm try to make a statement when i insert some numeric the system automatic return value*1000

***This is after the program running***

[image]

it works only once.

Comment: if we declare any variable as a certain data type and the value of the variable is exceeding the limit of the data type of the variable we get the error for overflow

Comment: The problem is not in the portion of code you have displayed.  How have you declared your variables?

Comment: Make automatic multiplication in VBA

Answer (score 2):

It looks like your `result2` variable is dim'ed as an integer. in wich case 1000 * 1000 is too large for an integer variable. An integer has to be between -32767 and 32767. So 1 milion can't be put into an integer.

If you change your `result2` to a long array you should be okay.

Comment: Make automatic multiplication in VBA

Answer (score 2):

I think, Problem is Worksheet_change is being called recursively because you are updating the value in same column.

You can handle this by using Application.EnableEvents. This will stop Worksheet_change event and after updating you can set it back to true.

```
Application.EnableEvents = False
set value in E column
Application.EnableEvents = True
```

Or You can simply use the following formula in a separate column (e.g. F) and paste it in entire column.

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(E2),E2*1000,0)
```

Comment: OP's code is designed to multiply 'in place', meaning the value in in column E is replaced by that value times 1000. So for your answer to work you would have to add the formula in a seperate column and paste the values to column E (and maybe delete the formulas from the seperate colum).

Comment: Yes i was updating the same in my answer. just completed. Thanks

Comment: Make automatic multiplication in VBA

Answer (score 1):

Instead of looping a range you could use `Array` which is faster:

```
Sub test()

    Dim arr As Variant

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

        'Import all values to an array
        arr = .Range("E10:E36")

        'Loop array
        For i = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)
            'Check if the value is numeric
            If IsNumeric(arr(i, 1)) Then
                'Multiple by 1000
                arr(i, 1) = arr(i, 1) * 1000
            End If
        Next i
        'Import array to the range
        .Range("E10:E36") = arr

    End With

End Sub
```